# JQuery Draggable content - show selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am using jQuery Draggable, to drag new elements to another div. This is all working well, however I want whatever element they have dragged, to show on the left in a different colour (to show it has been selected).

This is my codepen - https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/MWeXERP

So how can I have it, so if they have selected a journey this will show as black.

```
  $(".journey").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',opacity: 0.1,
    revert: "invalid",
  }).disableSelection();
```

This is the script targeting the draggable area, all is on the codepen.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use start and stop event to do what you want with a custom css class : https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-start

Answer (score 1):

You could make the "revert" a function and when the draggable item is placed in a valid droppable the draggable changes background-color.

```
revert: function(valid){
            if(valid)
                $(this).css("background-color","black");
            else
                return true;
        }
```

If the same draggable is drawn to a new droppable that droppable inherits the new background-color (black), in order to prevent this you could add a drag function to the draggable which unsets the background-color when moving the draggable .

```
drag: function(){
          $(this).css("background-color","unset");
      }
```

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/mistersven/pen/abZKEwy

Comment: Hi, this works however when clicking reset, this then breaks and you can't put another one in. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Also, you can't drag the item back out if you dont want it :(

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mistersven/pen/abZKEwy) with working reset button. Inspiration for [movable](http://www.pureexample.com/jquery-ui/draggable-options-scope.html)

Comment: Brilliant Sven thank you! So I imagine, that I need to update the code where you can drag them out of the the right? Back into the left?